# AJAX blocking div issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Cannot get working AJAX blocking div with following CSS... Any clue?
Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div id="busy"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function () { 
                $("#busy").show();
            },
            complete: function () { 
                $("#busy").hide();
            }
        });
```

**CSS**

```
#busy {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    background-color:grey;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your element has a `static` position, it needs to be positioned `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` to have dimensions

```
#busy {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    background-color:grey;
    z-index:9999;
}
```